# Mask RCNN demo code error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder, demo

I am trying to get the MASK RCNN demo code to work to see what else I need to download. I can't get past this error. AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'

Does anyone has suggestions on how to fix it, or what I need to download.

[image]

Comment: A starting point would be to make sure that the version of Tensorflow you have installed is a version supported by the `modellib` package you are using for the RCNN model.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. The source code on StackOverflow should be posted as text inside the question or as a link to the text if it's too long

Comment: Hi did you get the answer? i am facing a similar issue @Ramila

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue with `Tensorflow` version,You are using `Tensorflow version 2.x` but `placeholder` is available in Tensorflow version 1.x.
in `Tensorflow 2.x` Tensors are created with `tf.constant()` and `tf.Variable()`, You can check the demo code for `Tensorflow version 2`, since it has advantage over `Tensorflow Version 1` with many added functionalities and performance advantage.

If you want to migrate the code from `Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x` then you can check this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate).

Else downgrade the `Tensorflow` version to 1.x to run the existing code.